# How to enhance full text search at this query?

Tags: sql, full-text-search, database-administration

```
SELECT  id  ,
        classid ,
        periodical ,
        publishdate ,
        SUM(rate) pkrate ,
        dbo.GROUP_CONCAT(keywords) keywords
FROM    ( SELECT    10 rate ,
                    N'("ÇáÊÑÈíÉ æÇáÊÚáíã")=10' AS keywords ,
                    id ,
                    classid ,
                    periodical ,
                    publishdate
          FROM      news
          WHERE     CONTAINS (( title, body), N'("ÇáÊÑÈíÉ æÇáÊÚáíã")' )
          UNION
          SELECT    4 rate ,
                    N'("ÊáãíÐ")=4' AS keywords ,
                    id ,
                    classid ,
                    periodical ,
                    publishdate
          FROM      news
          WHERE     CONTAINS (( title, body), N'("ÊáãíÐ")' )
          UNION
          SELECT    4 rate ,
                    N'("ØÇáÈ")=4' AS keywords ,
                    id ,
                    classid ,
                    periodical ,
                    publishdate
          FROM      news
          WHERE     CONTAINS (( title, body), N'("ØÇáÈ")' )
          UNION
          SELECT    5 rate ,
                    N'("ØáÇÈ")=5' AS keywords ,
                    id ,
                    classid ,
                    periodical ,
                    publishdate
          FROM      news
          WHERE     CONTAINS (( title, body), N'("ØáÇÈ")' )
          UNION
          SELECT    5 rate ,
                    N'("ãÏÑÓ")=5' AS keywords ,
                    id ,
                    classid ,
                    periodical ,
                    publishdate
          FROM      news
          WHERE     CONTAINS (( title, body), N'("ãÏÑÓ")' )
          UNION
          SELECT    5 rate ,
                    N'("ãÏÇÑÓ")=5' AS keywords ,
                    id ,
                    classid ,
                    periodical ,
                    publishdate
          FROM      news
          WHERE     CONTAINS (( title, body), N'("ãÏÇÑÓ")' )
          UNION
          SELECT    5 rate ,
                    N'("ÊÑÈíÉ")=5' AS keywords ,
                    id ,
                    classid ,
                    periodical ,
                    publishdate
          FROM      news
          WHERE     CONTAINS (( title, body), N'("ÊÑÈíÉ")' )
          UNION
          SELECT    5 rate ,
                    N'("ÊÚáíã")=5' AS keywords ,
                    id ,
                    classid ,
                    periodical ,
                    publishdate
          FROM      news
          WHERE     CONTAINS (( title, body), N'("ÊÚáíã")' )
          UNION
          SELECT    5 rate ,
                    N'("ßáíÇÊ")=5' AS keywords ,
                    id ,
                    classid ,
                    periodical ,
                    publishdate
          FROM      news
          WHERE     CONTAINS (( title, body), N'("ßáíÇÊ")' )
          UNION
          SELECT    5 rate ,
                    N'("ÌÇãÚÉ")=5' AS keywords ,
                    id ,
                    classid ,
                    periodical ,
                    publishdate
          FROM      news
          WHERE     CONTAINS (( title, body), N'("ÌÇãÚÉ")' )
          UNION
          SELECT    5 rate ,
                    N'("ÌÇãÚÇÊ")=5' AS keywords ,
                    id ,
                    classid ,
                    periodical ,
                    publishdate
          FROM      news
          WHERE     CONTAINS (( title, body), N'("ÌÇãÚÇÊ")' )
          UNION
          SELECT    5 rate ,
                    N'("ÚÇã ÏÑÇÓì")=5' AS keywords ,
                    id ,
                    classid ,
                    periodical ,
                    publishdate
          FROM      news
          WHERE     CONTAINS (( title, body), N'("ÚÇã ÏÑÇÓì")' )
          UNION
          SELECT    5 rate ,
                    N'("ãäÇåÌ")=5' AS keywords ,
                    id ,
                    classid ,
                    periodical ,
                    publishdate
          FROM      news
          WHERE     CONTAINS (( title, body), N'("ãäÇåÌ")' )
          UNION
          SELECT    4 rate ,
                    N'("ãäåÌ")=4' AS keywords ,
                    id ,
                    classid ,
                    periodical ,
                    publishdate
          FROM      news
          WHERE     CONTAINS (( title, body), N'("ãäåÌ")' )
          UNION
          SELECT    5 rate ,
                    N'("ßáíÉ")=5' AS keywords ,
                    id ,
                    classid ,
                    periodical ,
                    publishdate
          FROM      news
          WHERE     CONTAINS (( title, body), N'("ßáíÉ")' )
          UNION
          SELECT    5 rate ,
                    N'("ÇãÊÍÇä")=5' AS keywords ,
                    id ,
                    classid ,
                    periodical ,
                    publishdate
          FROM      news
          WHERE     CONTAINS (( title, body), N'("ÇãÊÍÇä")' )
          UNION
          SELECT    5 rate ,
                    N'("ãÚÇáí ÇáÏßÊæÑ ÚÒÇã ÇáÏÎíá")=5' AS keywords ,
                    id ,
                    classid ,
                    periodical ,
                    publishdate
          FROM      news
          WHERE     CONTAINS (( title, body), N'("ãÚÇáí ÇáÏßÊæÑ ÚÒÇã ÇáÏÎíá")' )
          UNION
          SELECT    10 rate ,
                    N'("æÒíÑ ÇáÊÚáíã")=10' AS keywords ,
                    id ,
                    classid ,
                    periodical ,
                    publishdate
          FROM      news
          WHERE     CONTAINS (( title, body), N'("æÒíÑ ÇáÊÚáíã")' )
        ) T1
GROUP BY id ,
        classid ,
        periodical ,
        publishdate
HAVING  SUM(rate) >= 10
```

Comment: Please lay out your code.  Indenting with spaces will display as a code block.

Comment: Elaborate on your topic. What do you need to enchance? What is the current performance? Why doesn't it satisfy you? What have you tried to do it better? And for ducks sake, please, format your code.